# Can use `octane` (swoole) cache driver as default cache driver in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, swoole, laravel-octane

`Firstly, my English is bad. Sorry about that.`

Why I ask this question since cache with  `octane` (swoole) only available on runtime. Snippet on Laravel docs `the cached data will be flushed when the server is restarted`

=> Some parts of laravel cache before runtime like views, configs, routes, ...

So that I think if set `octane` (swoole) as default cache driver will occur some issue.

Comment: I don't think the fact that views/configs/routes being flushed on each request would cause any issue on other cached data.

Comment: @apokryfos in my case, I want use `swoole` as default and only cache driver on laravel octane app

Comment: I don't really see an issue with that. Just don't restart your server too much and be mindful of memory use and you should be fine

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks you! Your confirmation give me confidence to try it later

Comment: I was looking at swoole.co.uk and it seems like an application server / framework to handle sockets, rather than a cache server. Can you give more information to the lib you are using?

Comment: @DanielW. `Laravel` + `Laravel Octane with swoole driver` will give you this power. If outside `Laravel` sorry I don't know

Comment: Laravel Octane and Swoole are application server, they aren't cache servers.

Comment: @DanielW. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/octane#the-octane-cache It mentioned in here

Comment: @DanielW. I know it not really is a cache servers but it store in memory. And why not if I using `Octane swoole` and don't want a new cache servers